# Replacing everything but the matching regex string

Tags: regex, vba

I've searched for this answer but haven't found an answer that exactly works.

I have the following pattern where the hashes are any digit: 102###-###:#####-### or 102###-###:#####-####

It must start with 102 and the last set in the pattern can either be 3 or 4 digits.

The problem is that I can have a string with between 1-5 of these patterns in it with any sort of characters in between (spaces, letters etc). The Regex I posted below matches the patterns well but I am trying to select everything that is NOT this pattern so I can remove it.  The end goal is to extract all the patterns and just have all the patterns comma delimited as the output. (Pattern, Pattern, Pattern)  How do I accomplish this with regex?Perhaps there is a better way than trying to take this line? Thanks. This is using VBA.

Regex For Pattern:`(\D102\d{3}-\d{3}:\d{5}-\d{3,4}\D)`

String Example: `type:102456-345:56746-234 102456-345:56746-2343 FollowingCell#:102456-345:56746-234 exampletext#@$% 102456-345:56746-2345 stuff`

Comment: Please, put in tag language/technology that you use.

Comment: You forgot the closing parenthesis for your capture group.

Comment: Ehrm... Why remove everything around it if you can just match all the occurrences of the pattern?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the language in, and fixed the closing parenthesis. I'm just using the Regex library in VBA.

Comment: @UnderTheair try `(?<!\d)102\d{3}-\d{3}:\d{5}-\d{3,4}(?!\d)`

Comment: @UnderTheair when you say "*select everything that is NOT this pattern so I can remove it*" what's the exact expected output?

Comment: @tobias_k how would I do that? I can only seem to test that it exists not extract all the occurrences? Sorry, my understanding is not the best.

Comment: @UnderTheair I'm not familiar with VBA's regex library, but there _has_ to be a function for that. That's what regex are there for.

Comment: @tobias_k there is, it's `re.Matches()` where `re` is the regex object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to grab everything you don't need to remove it: That's more difficult. Just grab everything you need and do whatever you want with it.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9beQeD/1)

```
(?<!\d)102\d{3}-\d{3}:\d{5}-\d{3,4}(?!\d)
```

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##bVFNT8JAEL3zK8aiSUlsA7TFhGjQIBgTy0GMXrgs7QBNdrvNfkiJ4bfXKZugBy4zb2f3vbw3@70OMqmwaV5FJZXRsDxogyL8wNqE77i1nKlZXSnUupCl7qQytxzBtUEHYGnXkLKi9Ht0AHguBGhpVYbaqKLcAiNJhx7AM4cKx4P@ME5GQRQn42R0F4@CYRTDpWEEc8m53BN5ipx3LzOxZqLiaMhw9/H65qJSAtrYzcY7W1QITxooH9bka4F7h33Pn9xfrfIeiazyn@gYnOqYauLwbXz0J@0L7y@vyNqUKTPZbkqGMTO0KpJVGJ6GqP3/K3HEuVSALNuBOJOhKEnrdAswpW1LjuGXKgy@FSX6InxR0lba7/fCT8YtOqEFBScwK/P2Lzptd7/TNL8)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "type:102456-345:56746-234 102456-345:56746-2343 FollowingCell#:102456-345:56746-234 exampletext#@$% 102456-345:56746-2345 stuff"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(?<!\d)102\d{3}-\d{3}:\d{5}-\d{3,4}(?!\d)")
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    For each m as Match in mc
      Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(0).Value)
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

Result:

```
102456-345:56746-234
102456-345:56746-2343
102456-345:56746-234
102456-345:56746-2345
```

Comment: This worked. @tobias_k Yours worked too its just that I can't select multiple answers and his was more tailored to the language. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to select everything that is NOT this pattern so I can remove it. The end goal is to extract all the patterns and just have all the patterns comma delimited as the output

If you want to extract the patterns, then just do that, without removing everything around them. Example in Python: (Posted before the question's language was specified, but I'm sure the same can be done in VBA.)

```py
>>> import re
>>> p = r"102\d{3}-\d{3}:\d{5}-\d{3,4}"
>>> text = "type:102456-345:56746-234 102456-345:56746-2343 FollowingCell#:102456-345:56746-234 exampletext#@$% 102456-345:56746-2345 stuff"
>>> ",".join(re.findall(p, text))
'102456-345:56746-234,102456-345:56746-2343,102456-345:56746-234,102456-345:56746-2345'
```